# How to disable and uncheck the checkbox values from database fields..VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have retrieved checkbox checked values & put in textbox as 1,2,3,4,5...so on ...and inserted into database ... using vb.net

**Have a look at my database ..**

```
Name               checked                Date

Sumit              3,2                    11-Dec-2010
Manish             1,5,4                  11-Dec-2010 
Dobriyal           1,2,3,4                12-Dec-2010
```

I want when I search for the record of 11-Dec-2010 then checkbox 1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4, checkbox5 will be unchecked and disabled  for 11-Dec-2010...

Comment: checkbox2 and checkbox3 should be unchecked and disabled for 11-Dec-2010 or checkbo 1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4, checkbox5.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim checked = From chosen in db.Table Where chosen.date = "11/10/2010" Select chosen.checked

Dim boxes as new List (of string)
For each item in checked
   boxes.addrange(item.split(","c))
Next

Dim BoxNums = From boxnum in boxes Distinct Select "checkbox" + Cstr(boxnum)

For Each but As CheckBox In YourForm.Controls
   For Each boxname As String In boxnums
        If but.Name = boxname Then
            but.Checked = False
            but.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Okay, explaining time:

the code gets the nums from your table (since your method of storing  numbers is kinda lame i had to add addition code to trim the commas and select distinct values) all this done with LINQ, then i cycle through the checkbox controls of the form, if the selected cbox is selected to be disabled,disable it