# how to disabled and uncheck the checkbox values from database fields..VB.NET !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable and uncheck the checkbox values from database fields..VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416685/how-to-disable-and-uncheck-the-checkbox-values-from-database-fields-vb-net)

how to disabled and uncheck the checkbox values from database fields..

if i have entry in my database records as :

```
Name          Seats           Date

Sumit         1,3             11-Dec-2010
Sanjeev       2,4             12-Dec-2010
Manish        1,3,4           11-Dec-2010
```

I want on page load event the default date for todays is 11-Dec-2010 then checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4 will be disabled and unchecked state for 11-Dec-2010

as you see on the above database structure the seats for 11-Dec-2010 is 1,2,3,4 so the chekbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4 will be disabled...

I wanna this code snippet in VB.NET !! Can anybody help me in that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database - the `Seats` field is not normalized and should only hold *one* item.

Having comma delimited values in a field is bad practice. If you had a single value in it like the following:

```
Name          Seats           Date

Sumit         1               11-Dec-2010
Sumit         3               11-Dec-2010
Sanjeev       2               12-Dec-2010
Sanjeev       4               12-Dec-2010
Manish        1               11-Dec-2010
Manish        3               11-Dec-2010
Manish        4               11-Dec-2010
```

Removing a record would correlate to unchecking and adding one would correlate to checking a checkbox.

Comment: I didnt understand ! how to normalizes...

Comment: @user522211 - I have added an example.